# Google Play - Zero Supported Devices

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to publish an app, but no matter what I try the developer console is reporting that there are zero supported devices.
Google play store is showing zero supported devices, I don't know why. I searched everywhere but didn't get the answer
I tried to change the manifest.
Can someone help me?

> ```
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:supportsRtl="true"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>         <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait">a
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>         <activity android:name=".InfoActivity"
>             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

GRADLE

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.allegretti.countrypowerstation"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Can someone help me?

UPDATE
This library causes the problem
        compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

Comment: did you try change your config ??? for example `compileSdkVersion 25 / buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"`

Comment: Problem solved. This is the problem     compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark this as answered to help others in future.

Comment: I can't mark my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library causes the problem compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

Answer (score 1):

Try to change -> compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
to
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'